# Weird behavior of printf on a stm8l with COSMIC compiler

Tags: c, stm8

printf gives me weird extra values in some cases. What might be happening?

I'm manipulating values in an uint8_t array and printing it out to my terminal to verify if everything is correct. But for some reason I am getting weird values when I print a uint8_t - I get the expected value plus some other value (it is always the same extra value), as if I was printing a uint16_t or other 16bit value. I trimmed it all down to the following example:

This is the test code

```c
test_payload[0] = (uint8_t)0x58;
test_payload[1] = (uint8_t)0x7B;
test_payload[2] = (uint8_t)0x6B;
test_payload[3] = (uint8_t)0x05;
test_payload[4] = (uint8_t)0x4F;
test_payload[5] = (uint8_t)0x81;
test_payload[6] = (uint8_t)0x69;
test_payload[7] = (uint8_t)0x00;

printf("%x\n\r", test_payload[0]);
printf("%x\n\r", test_payload[1]);
printf("%x\n\r", test_payload[0] + test_payload[1]);

for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    printf("%x", test_payload[i]);
}
```

The output I get is

```
5803
7b03
d3
58037b0333034f03810369033
```

What is making it behave like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code fragment should produce `58`, but you do not output a newline, so any subsequent output will appear right after the `58`. It is possible that you output `86` in the code that follows the fragment. Post a complete program that exhibits the offending behavior, or change the format as `%x\n` to separate `58` from subsequent output.

Technically, `printf` expects an `unsigned int` argument for a `%x` conversion format, but an `int` value should work fine and `test_payload[0]` is promoted to `int` and passed as such to `printf`. You could try changing the format to `%hhx` or casting the argument as `(unsigned int)test_payload[0]`, but it would be **very surprising** that one of these changes alone fix the problem.

**EDIT:** from your extra information, it looks like the compiler for your embedded target is very peculiar. Definitely try casting the arguments as in

```
printf("%x\r\n", (unsigned int)test_payload[0]);
```

Observing that `printf("%x\n\r", test_payload[0] + test_payload[1]);` seems to work fine, the problem is not passing an `int` instead of an `unsigned int`, which would have been bad enough... It seems `printf()` passes `uint8_t` values incorrectly, in a non conforming way.

Another potential source of problems is if you forgot to include `<stdio.h>` and are calling `printf` without a definition with a prototype. The C Standard (**6.5.2.2 Function calls**) explicitly defines this call as having undefined behavior if the function is *defined* (in the library) with a prototype that includes an ellipsis (`...`).

Comment: That's the code right there. After it the microcontroller starts readings sensors and such, not printing anything in the nex few minutes. Also, if I make a while() loop to print the 8 values from the test_payload array, I get that 86 after each non-zero value. I'll put this into the question to give a better example.

Comment: Yes, just did the (unsigned int) cast and it worked. Realized it was a compiler thing and updated the question. Weird indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`%x` requires an `unsigned int` as parameter; If you want to print a single byte, e.g. as `uint8_t`, you need to write `%hhx`.

Comment: `uint8_t` arguments are promoted to `int` when passed to `printf` which should work fine for a `%x` conversion specification.

Comment: I tried this too and apparelty the compiler does not support it, I got a bunch of "hx" on the terminal.